# React Native render list of tags in a flatlist next to each other

Tags: reactjs, react-native, listview, expo

I am building a react-native app and in my settings page I want people to be able to add an item. When I render that item (The items may be different sizes) I want all of them to be rendered next to each other and overflow onto the line below them. I have tried using flexDirection : 'row' but that has not worked. I have also tried setting numColumns but since the items are different sizes, that also does not work.

What I have so far for my flatList:

```
<FlatList
              showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
              numColumns = {3}
              style = {{flex : 1, height : '100%', width : '100%', borderRadius : 20, marginTop : 12,flexDirection : 'row'}}
              data = {[...this.state.classes, 'ADD']}
              renderItem = {({item, index}) => {
                return (
                  <View key = {index} style = {{marginHorizontal : 16, marginVertical : 4, alignSelf: 'flex-start',height : 35, backgroundColor : '#f2f2f2', borderRadius : 40, alignItems : "center", justifyContent : "space-between", paddingLeft: 16, paddingRight : 16, flexDirection : 'row'}}>
                    <Text style = {{fontSize : 14, paddingRight : 16,fontFamily : fonts.subtitle, color : "#333"}} >{item}</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => this.deleteClass(index)} style = {{alignItems : "center", justifyContent : "center", }}>
                      <Ionicons name = "ios-close" size = {20} color = {colors.error}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                )
              }}
              />
```

Comment: Try wrapping the View with flexDirection around the flatlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `contentContainerStyle` to modify the default behaviour of Flatlist which renders new row in next line.

The flatlist/sectionlist/scrollview has a **invisible** container which holds the items together.You can try it for your problem.

I am attaching a expo snack so for you to use it.
[Flatlist example](https://snack.expo.io/@karthik.01/flatlist-wraping)

Hope it helps !